# How to better store images in android application?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I need to create simple card game. There are many cards. My first idea was just to store images with db room. When I searched about it there were several comments that is not suggested to do but reasons why were not listed. I guess I have two options: store cards as drawables or store them into sqlite. So my question: which way is better or maybe there is another better idea how to store cards? And why is it bad practice to insert images in db? Not asking about implementation, just direction)

Comment: why would you want to store it into a db ?

Comment: You can just save it as drawable if images are not too huge in size (MBs).  if they are huge thats gonna make your APK bigger in size so its better you download then afterwards and save it in storage .

Comment: you can convert it into an array of bytes using type converters

Comment: @a_local_nobody need to access them fast and conformable. I thought it would be better to use db for these purposes.

Comment: use them as drawable resources, ii can't think of a reason why a db would be better